# Small Android AsyncTask project

Tags: java, android

I created a small Android project with an AsyncTask. It simulates a time consuming task.

Please review my code and tell me what you would do on a different way and why.  Comments not specific to Android but general software development are welcome.

CounterTask.java:

```
package my.tasks;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * @author 2
 * 
 *         Simulates a time consuming task, counts in the background from 0 to
 *         the given value in first parameter. Its progress is published via an
 *         integer which is a percentual value 0..100. The task may not
 *         complete, it may fail or it may be cancelled by the user. In case of
 *         success it returns true.
 */
public class CounterTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Boolean> {

    private static final long DELAY = 100;
    private static final int PROBABILITY_TO_FAIL_EVERY_STEP = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "CounterTask";
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Random random;

    /**
    * @param progressDialog
    * a ProgressDialog the task can use to display its progress.
    */
    public CounterTask(ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
        this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
        this.progressDialog.setMax(100);
        this.random = new Random();
    }

    /*
    * (non-Javadoc)
    * 
    * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
    * 
    * Set params[0] to the maximum value you want the task to count to.
    */
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        validateParams(params);
        int count_max = params[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < count_max; i++) {
            int progressPercent = calculateProgressPercent(i, count_max);
            publishProgress(progressPercent);
            Log.i(TAG, "Counter: " + Integer.toString(i));
            Log.i(TAG, "Progress published: " + Integer.toString(progressPercent) + "%");
            if (sleep() == false) {
                return false;
            }
            if (doesFail(PROBABILITY_TO_FAIL_EVERY_STEP)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Background fails.");
                return false;
            }
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Background succeeds.");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
        Log.i(TAG, "Background cancelled.");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        String message = null;
        if (result)
            message = "Background succeeded.";
        else
            message = "Background failed.";
        Log.i(TAG, message);
        createAlertDialog(message).show();
    }

    private Dialog createAlertDialog(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(progressDialog.getContext());
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.setMessage(message).setTitle("Result").setCancelable(true).create();
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    /**
    * Helper method to decide if the task fails in this step.
    * 
    * @param probabilityToFail
    *            Value 0..100 the probability to fail.
    * @return true if it fails, false if not
    */
    private boolean doesFail(int probabilityToFail) {

        int prob = random.nextInt(100);
        if (prob < probabilityToFail)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    /**
    * The thread sleeps from step to step to simulate a time consuming task.
    * 
    * @return
    */
    private boolean sleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(DELAY);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private int calculateProgressPercent(int done, int max) {
        done = done * 100;
        return done / max;
    }

    private void validateParams(Integer... integers) {
        if (integers == null || integers.length != 1 || integers[0] < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package my.application;

import my.tasks.CounterTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnCancelListener {
    private CounterTask counterTask;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();

        switch (id) {
        case R.id.startButton:
            ProgressDialog progressDialog = createProgressDialog();
            progressDialog.show();
            CounterTask ct = new CounterTask(progressDialog);
            counterTask = (CounterTask) ct.execute(100);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    private ProgressDialog createProgressDialog() {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.setMax(100);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Progress");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(this);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        return progressDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
        counterTask.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks good.  You could put the progressDialog creation and show it in onPreExecute: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute(). It will run in the UI thread and will encapsulate more of the dialog logic.

You can cut out a few lines here

```java
String message = null;
if (result)
    message = "Background succeeded.";
else
    message = "Background failed.";
```

becomes

```java
String message = result ? "Background succeeded." : "Background failed";
```

Answer (score 1):

Conditional operator can be used to improve the following method:

```
private boolean doesFail(int probabilityToFail) {

    int prob = random.nextInt(100);
    if (prob < probabilityToFail)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Can be improved as

```
private boolean doesFail(int probabilityToFail) {
    return (random.nextInt(100) < probabilityToFail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- do not pass ProgressDialog as parameter  in constructor 
  (what will happend when activity will be recreated and task is still running or finished?)  read more about **SERIALIZATION**
- don't use keyword this in constructor if u not calling other constructor involving creation of its object or using it as a qualifier when referencing fields
- use onPreExecute() to show ProgressDialog like this:

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
       /** show progress dialog */
      showProgressDialog(_context,_message);
  }

  /** show pd method */
  private void showProgressDialog(Context context, String message) {
      /** check if progress dialog is not already created or if context didn't changed - eg. during screen rotation */
      if(_progressDialog == null || _progressDialog.getContext().equals(context)) {
          /** create progress dialog */
          _progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
          _progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
      }
      /** set message */
      _progressDialog.setMessage(message);
      /** show pd */
      _progressDialog.show();
  }
  ```
- always find places when your task could be terminatet by you or other factors and try dismiss progress dialog

  ```
  private void dismissProgressDialog() {
      try {
          /** check if  progress dialog is showing */
          if (_progressDialog != null && _progressDialog.isShowing()) {
              /** dismiss login dialog */
              _progressDialog.dismiss();
          }
      } catch (Exception e) {
          // Handle or log or ignore
      } finally {
          _progressDialog = null;
      }
  }
  ```

  - onPostExecute you should dismiss progress dialog not showing it
  - to show your result create a callback to Activity

define interface:

```
public interface AsyncTaskResultListener<T> {

    /**  notifies Activity when task is done.
     *   @return true if result parsed OK
     *   other way false to repeat with RepeatTask()*/
    boolean onTaskComplete(T result);
    void repeatTask();
}
```

in async task:

```
    AsyncTaskResultListener<T> _callback;
    Context _context;

    MyAsyncTask(Context context) {
       /** check for valid context */
        if(Activity.class.isAssignableFrom(context.getClass()) {
            _contex = context;
            /** check for valid callback */
             if(AsyncTaskResultListener.class.isAssignableFrom(context.getClass()) {
                 /** cast it to interface */
                 _callback = (AsyncTaskResultListener<T>) context;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(T result) {
       if(_callback!=null) {
            if(!callback.onTaskComplete(result) {
                /** repeat task */
                callback.repeatTask()
            }
        }
        /** dismiss pd */
    }
```

in activity:

```
public MyActivity exrtends Activity implements AsyncTaskResultListener<T> {

    @Override 
    boolean onTaskComplete(T result) {
        /** do work with your result 
        if satisfied return true, to repeat task return false */
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void repeatTask() {
        /** free to make decision what to do */
    }
}
```

i got little more to point out but my hands have enough